# back folded corner using css or javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How do i create a back folded corner for a menu like below using CSS, JQUERY or Javascript. Or is there any kind of library allow to do this.

Thank you very much

[image: Folded Corner Menu]

Comment: http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/css-powered-ribbons-the-clean-way/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ipeho5/5 **or** http://jsfiddle.net/yKpzK/ **or** http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/ hope all of these helps you! **and** +1 to the above comment

Comment: Thank you very much .... the first link is really realy helpfull one